# Jquery using contains to find text containing parentheses

Tags: jquery, parentheses, contain

Maybe it is simple, but I can't make it work...
here is my code:

```
function br_text() {$("#text_fields:contains('\(') ").each(
   function() 
      {
      $(this).css('color','red')
      alert($(this).text())
      }
)
}
```

I need to get the object that contains a string with a parentheses
(I've tried without the escape character, seems to be the same.)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: it is looking fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qeG7S/1/

Comment: my doubt is towards the selector `#text_fields`.... might be here are more than one element with id `text_fields`

Comment: So your trying to get the **Element Tag Name** of each element having **()**?

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
function br_text() {
    $("body *:contains('(')").css("color", "red");
}
```

## Example